# Make a Pie-Specials Menu, dependent on selection type

Tags: python, add-on, pie-menu

I want to do the following with Python:

I have 3 different menus, and I want them to appear, dependent on the selection mode.

So when I'm in faceselectmode, I want with the same button a different menu as if I'm in vertselectmode.

I think, with a for loop that could be possible, but I don't now how to set variables that makes sense and also the rest of that code could be complex.

So I just need a for loop which checks in which select mode I am in. Because it's possible that there could be more options chosen, I thought that the best solution would be to get only a special menu, when there is only one selection type.

So that's the code I have so far (doesn't work) the bool variables also could be one step too much.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu

select_vert=bool

select_edge=bool

select_face=bool

tool_settings.mesh_select_mode=tsm

for bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode in type #what?

    if  type ='VERT'
    select_vert=True
    select_edge=False
    select_face=False

    elif type ='EDGE'
    select_vert=False
    select_edge=True
    select_face=False

    elif type = 'FACE'
    select_vert=False
    select_edge=False
    select_face=True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In blenders text editor you can find a [template for creating a pie menu](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/ui_pie_menu.py). You will probably want to turn your script [into an addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html) to make your menu available every time you start blender.

Starting with the pie template, you want to alter the menus `draw()` to work how you want.

In the context that you get in the draw method, you can access [`tool_settings.mesh_select_mode`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ToolSettings.html#bpy.types.ToolSettings.mesh_select_mode) which is the three boolean values for the current select mode setting. You then test them to decide if you add the related items.

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    pie = layout.menu_pie()
    sel_mode = context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode
    if sel_mode[0]: # vertex on
        pie.operator('mesh.remove_doubles')
        pie.operator('mesh.merge')
        if not sel_mode[1]:
            # only vert select - don't show if edge sel is also active
            pie.operator('mesh.bevel', text='Vertex Bevel').vertex_only=True
    if sel_mode[1]: # edge on
        pie.operator('mesh.mark_seam')
        pie.operator('mesh.edge_rotate').use_ccw=False
        pie.operator('mesh.bevel', text='Edge Bevel').vertex_only=False
    if sel_mode[2]: # face on
        pie.operator('mesh.flip_normals')
        pie.operator('mesh.inset')
        pie.operator('mesh.poke')
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. The templates you mentioned, I already used or got it from elsewhere. (I modifiy the official piemenus for my Spacemouse).

Comment: I've used your code to enahnce my specials menu suite and it worked well. You mentioned the addon template. Because I made a whole bunch of scripts (13) I would to enable it with an _init File but that doesn't worked. I Asked a Question but got no awnster, do you may know something? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109570/python-code-problem-of-a-modifed-addon-using-spacemouse-pro-with-blender-with-m